# Write in Urdu font

Tags: xetex, packages, natbib, texmaker

I want to write some lines in **Urdu font** in Tex writing. Someone help me that which packages I must use and how I write in .tex file, either in Urdu text or in English text. Please help me with a example. And also tell me that how can I update **natbib** reference packages file after using packages for Urdu writing. I am using TexMaker in Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A starting point is [`xelatex`](http://tug.org/xetex/) format and the [`polyglossia`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) package. I have downloaded and installed the [Scheherazade](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=Scheherazade#1fd0063a) font and I enclose a result of my efforts. I am sorry if I misspelled the Urdu terms. I haven't tested that but I think that you can wrap your Urdu words and BibTeX/BibLaTeX should processed them, it is worth some experiments. It would be great to have some samples of books (a bib file) from you and how the output should look like.

```
%! xelatex mal-urdu.tex
% To download: http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=Scheherazade#1fd0063a
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5]{Amiri} % or Scheherazade after installing the font
\begin{document}
Text before. \texturdu{ وہ کتاب ہے۔ میں جا رہا ہوں} Text after.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: When I run the .tex file I got the error....! LaTeX Error: File `xltxtra.sty' not found.

Comment: Try to comment out that line, but it looks that your TeX distribution is limited in XeTeX use (MikTeX user?).

Comment: Sorry I am new to tex writing and I can't get you, can you please clarify me

Comment: Please try to change line with `\usepackage{xltxtra}` to `%\usepackage{xltxtra}` and report back if there is an improvement after running `xelatex` on your TeX file.

Comment: I tried it I got a message that .... ! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".... and when run as **xelatex** I got an error message .... ! LaTeX Error: File `bidi.sty' not found.

Comment: Hm, that's a part of the `polyglossia` package. Your TeX distribution is somehow limited, it would be worth upgrading it to TeX Live 2013 or Mac TeX 2013. Can you please add `\usepackage{fontspec}` below this line `%\usepackage{xltxtra}`? If even `fontspec` package is not available on your computer, it am running out of the options.

Comment: Now I read your question carefully. You must upgrade your Ubuntu by `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`.

Comment: ok then, it takes a long time. It is almost 2GB, I hope you'll be there :)

Comment: I'll be glad if you could write if upgrade helped. Btw, is my example properly typeset from the Urdu point of view? I am not certain if ligatures are properly typeset.

Comment: after `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` all the packages problems are solve, but I got an error... ! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "Scheherazade" cannot be found.

Comment: You are missing the font, is my guess, right? :-) I see! Replace `{Scheherazade}` by `{Amiri}`, it is not that beautiful, but it should work. The Amiri font family is present on your computer after that upgrade.

Comment: :) Yes, I make it.... thanks a lot. I also install {Scheherazade} from Ubuntu software center, it works fine.