# XeLatex generating "! Missing } inserted" error (Arabic Fonts)

Tags: fonts, xetex, miktex, polyglossia, winedt

I am trying to embed 'Arabic Word' in a paper with main language as English.
I have gone through following steps:-

1. Installed Scheherazade Font
2. Downloaded polyglossia Package

I tried code from   [This Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171128/write-in-urdu-font)  and it worked fine as independent file. but when i embedded it into another .tex file. it did not compile.
Packages i have used are as follows:-

```
\documentclass[3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5] {Scheherazade} 
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
\let\@oddhead\@empty
\let\@evenhead\@empty
\def\@oddfoot{}%
\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{my title}
\author %...
\address %..
\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
 %...
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
 %...
 \end{keyword}
 \end{frontmatter}
 \section{Bibliography styles}
 Text before. \texturdu{ وہ کتاب ہے۔ میں جا رہا ہوں} Text after.
 There are various bibliography styles ....
  \section*{References}
  \end{document}
```

I get following error and the *.tex file wont compile:-

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmtt.fd")
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
            }
l.95 \end{frontmatter}
? 
Process has been terminated ...
```

What is wrong with the code. (i am using winedt 9 with mikTex 2.9)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Would you change your snippet of code into a minimal but complete example?  The lines about graphics probably aren’t needed to reproduce the problem, but `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` certainly are.  A minimal example will help us locate the problem.

Comment: Bad interaction of `elsarticle` with `bidi` is the most probable diagnosis.

Comment: but i need to insert some 'arabic' (urdu i mean) type of words. is there any turn around? the class elsarticle is the requirement of the journal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bidi` package loaded by `polyglossia` together with the Urdu language definition file doesn't know about `elsarticle`, so it redefines `\maketitle` as if it were the one in `article`, which is fully incompatible with what `elsarticle` expects.

Here's a workaround.

```
\documentclass[3p]{elsarticle}

% save \maketitle as defined by elsarticle
\let\elsmaketitle\maketitle
% and restore it at begin document
\AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\elsmaketitle}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5] {Scheherazade} 
\usepackage{graphicx}        

\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
\let\@oddhead\@empty
\let\@evenhead\@empty
\def\@oddfoot{}%
\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{my title}
\author{}
\address{}
\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
something
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
something
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Bibliography styles}

Text before. \texturdu{ وہ کتاب ہے۔ میں جا رہا ہوں} Text after.
There are various bibliography styles ....

\section*{References}

\end{document}
```

[image]