# "Missing $ inserted" when using "\setotherlanguages{arabic}"

Tags: fonts, xetex, polyglossia

I get `Missing $ inserted` error when using `\setotherlanguages{arabic}` to allow for Arabic text in Latex. The error appears only when specific templates are used, with custom definition. For example, in the code shown below, it appears at `\begin{abstract}`, which is defined as a part of the template.
This is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252353/xelatex-generating-missing-inserted-error-arabic-fonts). But when saving abstract after `\usepackage[hyperref]{acl2020}`  and restoring like in the solution the error persist and `\begin{document} ended by \end{abstract}` and `\begin{document} ended by \end{list}`appear

Here's the code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{acl2020}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\ttfamily\small}
\usepackage{microtype}
\newcommand\BibTeX{B\textsc{ib}\TeX}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Noto Naskh Arabic}

\title{Example Title}

\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
....
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The package `acl2020` does not appear to be a package that's distributed with the standard TeX distributions. is it available online somewhere?

Comment: It's a part of a template to be used for a conference submission. Here's a link to the template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acl-2020-proceedings-template/zsrkcwjptpcd.

Comment: A source for the style file that doesn't require an Overleaf account:  http://acl2020.org/downloads/acl2020-templates.zip.

Comment: Thanks. Were you able to reproduce the error?

Comment: I'm actually getting a different error. There's an instruction on line 456 of the file acl2020.sty that causes a crash (something unintelligible about a failed patch instruction...). After I commented out the offending instruction, I also had to comment out the directive `\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Noto Naskh Arabic}` since I don't have that font on my system (MacTeX2019). Once that was done, though, the test file compiles without further ado. I should add that I also commented out the instruction `\usepackage{xunicode}` so that I could compile your document under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Can you point what the instruction you commented in the style file? 
I can't get rid of the error unless I comment out  `\setotherlanguages{arabic}` but then I won't be able to use Arabic text.

Comment: It's the instruction right after `\RequirePackage{etoolbox}`: `\patchcmd\@combinedblfloats{..}{...}{}{...}`. For one reason or another -- possibly because `hyperref` has been patched recently, but I'm not sure -- the `\patchcmd` instruction fails.

Comment: The error persists still. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: Comment out both lines 455 and 456 in the .`sty` file. I compile OK under xelatex after that (I have the font). The documentation "10 Latex Compilation Issues" (p 6) mentions the patch (it's intended for urls crossing page boundaries). Contact the author (address is in the .`sty` file; they are expecting bugs. Unrelated: I like the line numbering method very  much!

Comment: Hypothesis 1: just a guess -- what might possibly be happening is that patching hyperref's url processing produces a `\:` somewhere along the way (math mode medium space). Hypothesis 2: some other math mode item (_, e.g.) is straying into the picture.